# NodeJS - Framework Recommandations?

Tags: node.js, frameworks

Hej community!

I've completed some courses around nodejs on udemy the last days. Yeah, I'm pretty new to Server-Side JS.

I would like to build an simple interface as frontend which can trigger an api that serves the following functions: donwload a website via wget; push that website to an git repo.

Any recommandations on what frameworks i should look at, respectively are easy to start with?

Thanks so far!
BR Bernd

Comment: Welcome to SO! This solely depends on your preference. Popular frontend frameworks are Vue & Angular. You can also do everything with plain JS & HTML.

Comment: Hej tpschmidt! Thanks for messaging. Yeah the frontend part won't be that hard, i will go with Angular or may React. May you know any good Framework for the shell (wget, git push) part? I've seeen NestJS or Hapi, but i'm not sure about it.

Comment: I'm heavily using NestJS for a lot of my services and I'm very happy with it. it's easy to use and offers a lot of functions similar to what Spring gives you at java. Can recommend.

Comment: For gaining Confidence you can start with the framework you learned in the Udemy course, I believe you wrote code while watching the course, 

if this is true you can move ahead NestJs is pretty cool and forces one to write clean code I would recommend it, 

but if false try to write those codes.

Comment: yeah i attend a fullstack class where i wrote some tasks myself (react & express) - i will give NestJS a try - THANKS